# Is it safe to use struct members as references to memory offsets?

Tags: c

On the ARM Information Center site, they had [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3750.html) suggestion for using structs to map variables to memory addresses.

```
#define PORTBASE 0x40000000

typedef struct Port
{
    uint32_t reg0;
    uint32_t reg1;
    uint32_t reg2;
} Port;

volatile struct Port * const reg_p = (struct Port *)PORTBASE;
```

However, I have seen someone else suggest that compilers can add padding between members of a struct object and the only way to ensure this doesn't happen is to use the packed attribute, as in GCC `__attribute__((__packed__))`, for example.

It seems to me that padding would only be introduced by the compiler to align member boundaries, but I don't see in the C99 standard that it explicitly states this shouldn't happen in other cases. In fact, it seems like it says it could happen.

From C99 section 6.7.2.1,

> 12
>
> Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned
>   in an implementationdefined manner appropriate to its type.
>
> 13
>
> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which
>   bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which
>   they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.
>
> 15
>
> There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

Given the above example, is it guaranteed that reg1 will be exactly 32-bits offset from reg0 without telling the compiler not to add padding?

Comment: You could always use a `uint32_t[3]` and be safe.

Comment: +1 immediately for a good alternative. I'd still like to know about this though. If it's a bad idea, I'd like to eliminate it from anything I do in the future.

Comment: Their suggestion applies to their own `armcc` compiler. But of course C, as usual, does not guarantee anything.

Comment: I think the only real guarantee is that the struct will start with the first member... The ABI can specify a padding of 8, 16 or n bytes

Comment: I read the part you quoted as all bets are off.  Note `implementation defined manner`: you can drive a truck through this hole.  Also `have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared` just means that addresses increase; no units specified, no guarantee there won't be padding in between members.

Comment: @KerrekSB I did find out something I didn't really consider before. While the sizeof uint32_t[3] is almost guaranteed to be equal to the size of all its elements combined, something like Port[3] is not.

Comment: If you are using such adresses, then you are tied to some specific architecture anyway. Not much of a portabillity in this code AFAIK. So check the assembly output if it creates teh correct code for your machine, and then it works. Looking at the standard is mostly of interest if you plan to be portable, which I don't really see in this case.

Comment: @dsell002, where you get this from? The size of an array is by definition the multiple of the size of its members, `sizeof(T[N]) == sizeof(T)*N`. Otherwise you could never have a function like `malloc` working consistently.

Comment: Not quite: The size of `Port[3]` is also three times the size of `Port`, but *not* necessarily nine times the size of `uint32_t`.

Comment: @JensGustedt that was definitely NOT what I'd read earlier. Somehow Kerrek SB was able to take my completely false comment and understand what I'd intended to say. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Read the docs for your compiler.  #pragma pack(1) works on most Microsoft compilers and there are tons of drivers I've seen for DOS;OS/2;Win16;Win32 that rely on the pattern you describe.  There have been a few RISC processors where this didn't work (A mid 90s MIPS comes to mind, but I don't remember exactly).  Alignment problems (I'm told) had a fair amount to do with MS dropping support for other architectures in early WinNT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding between the members is added, so that Values are aligned to 32Bit(depends on architecture)
e.g. a uint32_t should start at an aligned offset 4*2^x to be faster accessible as
a normal 32bit Pointer can be used, as you struct consists only of 32Bit values
this is automatically true, if PORTBASE is an Aligned address.

Therefore the Compiler should in this case not add padding,
but you can always add

```
__attribute__((__packed__))
```

to be sure.

The Compiler would add padding in cases like:

```
struct
{
    uint8_t  a;
    uint32_t b;
}
```

where b would end up on an unaligned address.

The problem is that for arm you might get Compilers that are not completely C99 compatible.