# Algorithm to compare two date time stamps

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to implement a timestamp comparison in C (not using any libraries).

I am trying to figure out an optimal algorithm as the routine is going to be used intensively.

My input data is two time stamps, a and b, each of one comprises the following:

```
year
month
day
hour
minute
```

In C pseudocode:

```c
struct Timestamp {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minute;
};

struct Timestamp a;
struct Timestamp b;
```

I am trying several approaches including nested if's and a switch combining each value:

```
int timestamp_comparison(int a, int b) {
    if(a>b) return 2;
    if(a=b) return 1;
    if(a<b) return 0;
}
...
c_year = timestamp_comparison(a.year, b.year);
c_month = timestamp_comparison(a.month, b.month);
c_day = timestamp_comparison(a.day, b.day);
c_hour = timestamp_comparison(a.hour, b.hour);
c_minute = timestamp_comparison(a.minute, b.minute);

comparison = c_year * 10000 + c_month * 1000 + c_day * 100 + c_hour * 10 + c_minute;
...
```

But I would like to know if there is an already algorithm I could leverage on.
I do not like to use external libraries.

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: If you're going for an optimal overall program, you might want to revisit your timestamp structure. Using tuples of (year, month, day, hour, minute) is classically difficult, classically bug-ridden, and inefficient to boot. If you're going to be manipulating timestamps intensively, consider using representations that allow you to carry an entire timestamp around in a single (long) integer, such as `time_t`, or a composite number yyyymmddHHMMSS. or a pair of numbers for the Julian day and the time within the day.

Comment: Do you care about time zones and daylight saving time?

Comment: @steve-summit Thanks for your suggestion. I am exploring the way you suggest. The reason for using tuples is that they are used to retrieve memory indexed data (multiple dimension array). Regarding your second question no I do not care about time zones and daylight saving time. They are financial timestamps and therefore they are ET, begin on Sunday evening and end on Friday evening.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using return values `0`, `1` and `2`, I suggest to use `<0`, `0` and `>0`. This is more common, matches the semantics of `strcmp` etc., `qsort` or `bsearch` and can be implemented using simple subtraction and comparison with 0.

```
/*
 * @retval <0 if a < b
 * @retval 0 if a == b
 * @retval >0 if a > b
 */
int compare_timestamps(struct Timestamp a, struct Timestamp b)
{
    int result;

    result = a.year - b.year;
    if(result != 0) return result;

    result = a.month - b.month;
    if(result != 0) return result;

    result = a.day - b.day;
    if(result != 0) return result;

    result = a.hour - b.hour;
    if(result != 0) return result;

    result = a.minute - b.minute;

    return result;
}
```

As mentioned in Jim Mischel's comment, the algorithm assumes that the subtraction doesn't result in integer rollover. This is valid for normal values of `month`, `day`, `hour` and `minute` fields. It is a reasonable assumption for "usual" year values. It will not be valid for the `year` field if `abs(a.year) + abs(b.year) > INT_MAX`. To handle `year` values in the full range of `INT_MIN`..`INT_MAX` the algorithm would have to be changed.

Comment: The smart bit of this means you can use the idiom that `compare_timestamp(a,b) op 0` for any relational operator `op` has the natural meaning. For example `compare_timestamp(a,b) < 0` is true iff a < b, `compare_timestamp(a,b) != 0` is true iff a!=b and so on for all of `<`.`<=`,`=`,`!=`,`>=` and `>`. But why not use `<time.h>`?

Comment: @Persixty Of course you could create a `struct tm` from the `struct Timestamp` as defined in the question, but converting `struct tm` to `time_t` for comparison is probably more expensive as the question doesn't require to calculate the exact difference. Is there any better way to compare two `struct tm` than comparing (subtracting) the results of `mktime`?

Comment: Using the `struct tm` from `<time.h>` has its downsides. It has redundant members (`tm_sec`,`tm_wday`,`tm_yday` and `tm_isdst`) to the purpose here.
There is (as you point out) a non-trivial cost to `mktime()` when the member by member comparison you propose will suffice and only compares as many values as required. I've thrown it into the mix because as a matter of good practice you should prefer to use standard structures unless you can really justify the deviation....

Comment: I'm not aware of any better way (even in assembler) or comparing/ordering integers than by subtraction and considering the sign of the result (your way).
But we should always be sceptical of premature optimization. I'd consider using <time.h> and lazy use of `mktime()` until the OP is sure that's a genuine bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on time.h. I will do some tests with time.h, I was not aware this was a possibility. I am coming from a Python code that I need to optimize, it might be the case than even not being the most optimized option it might be fast enough.

Comment: Straightforward, easy to understand, and easy to prove correct. Excellent answer.

Comment: One thing to note is that the code assumes the values won't be negative, which is a reasonable assumption. However, if they can be negative then you have to be careful about using subtraction as a substitute for comparison because integer rollover can bite you.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing the timestamps, 2 concerns come into play

**Range of year**

If the used range of `.year` is `[INT_MIN...INT_MAX]`, avoid `a.year - b.year` as it may overflow.

**Primary values**

Are the members *always* in their primary range?  Example: Is `minute` in the range 0-59?

Is so, a simple compare and returning -1,0,1 uses the common C idiom `(a>b) - (a<b)`, something many compilers recognize and emit efficient code.

```
int timestamp_compare(const struct Timestamp *ts2, const struct Timestamp *ts1) {
  if (ts1->year  != ts2->year)  return (ts2->year  > ts1->year)  - (ts2->year  < ts1->year);
  if (ts1->month != ts2->month) return (ts2->month > ts1->month) - (ts2->month < ts1->month);
  if (ts1->day   != ts2->day)   return (ts2->day   > ts1->day)   - (ts2->day   < ts1->day);
  if (ts1->hour  != ts2->hour)  return (ts2->hour  > ts1->hour)  - (ts2->hour  < ts1->hour);
  return (ts2->day > ts1->day) - (ts2->day < ts1->day);
}
```

If not, form a linear count of minutes and then compare.

```
long long minutes(const struct Timestamp *ts) {
  return ((tbd_day_number(ts->year, ts->month, ts->day)*24LL + ts->hour)*60 + ts->minute;
}

int timestamp_compare(const struct Timestamp *ts2, const struct Timestamp *ts1) {
  long long m1 = minutes(ts1);
  long long m2 = minutes(ts2);
  return (m2 > m1) - (m2 < m1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your struct contains its members in a sorted manner, like in your case, (year is more significant than month, and so on...) and since in a struct, members are 'most likely' to be stored in a contiguous manner:
see: [Using Contiguous Memory of C Struct Members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461364/using-contiguous-memory-of-c-struct-members)

you can try using byte by byte comparison like so:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

// members of struct are stored contigously
struct Timestamp
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minute;
};


int timestamp_comparison(const struct Timestamp a, const struct Timestamp b)
{
    unsigned i;
    unsigned struct_size = sizeof(struct Timestamp) / sizeof(int);
    const int* t1 = (const int*)&a;
    const int* t2 = (const int*)&b;

    // compare byte by byte
    for (i = 0; i < struct_size; i++)
    {
        if (*t1 != *t2)
            return *t1 - *t2;

        ++t1;
        ++t2;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // example
    struct Timestamp a = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1};
    struct Timestamp b = {1, 1, 1, 7, 1};
    int comp = timestamp_comparison(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not saying this is better, than the already posted answer, just different. And for any other structs like yours, it'll work the same way.

Comment: Why compare as bytes, when it's just as easy and far more intuitive to compare as ints?

Comment: No particular reason. In this case, yes comparing as ints might be more appropriate. Just thought, that this would be more reusable, as the variables could be smaller in size, than an integer.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think this won't work. It depends on the order of bytes in memory. Intel CPUs (little endian) store an integer with the low bytes first. So the value 0xDEAD is stored in memory with 0xAD at the lower address and 0xDE at the higher address. Your function will compare the low bytes first. Some other CPUs store values the other way (big endian). On those, this would compare the high bytes first.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Never heard of endiannes before. Not to mention the unsignedness may have messed up things as well. Edited. Is this what you suggested?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea. This assumes, as you point out, that the members are stored contiguously. And also with no padding.

Answer (score -1):

here a minor improvement:

Your PC is working in binary so base 2 is what he can best

You could replace:

```
comparison = c_year * 10000 + c_month * 1000 + c_day * 100 + c_hour * 10 + c_minute;
```

by (your values are all lower than 4) so you can:

```
comparison = c_year * 256 + c_month * 64 + c_day * 16 + c_hour *4 + c_minute;
```

Or this (less readable but 'without' arithmetic):

```
comparison = c_year << 8 | c_month <<6 | c_day <<4 | c_hour <<2 | c_minute;
```

But if you really have a speed improvement by this, can only be validated with profiling.

depending on your data it could be faster only to compare what you need:

```
int val;
if(1!=(val=timestamp_comparison(a.year, b.year)))
  return val;
if(1!=(val=timestamp_comparison(a.month, b.month)))
  return val;
if(1!=(val=timestamp_comparison(a.c_day, b.c_day)))
  return val;
if(1!=(val=timestamp_comparison(a.c_hour, b.c_hour)))
  return val;
return timestamp_comparison(a.c_minute, b.c_minute);
```

But as I mentioned above, profiling is you friend when it is about optimization.

---

P.s.

```
if(a>b) return 2;
if(a=b) return 1;
if(a<b) return 0;
```

is a bit unusual definition. More common is :

```
if(a>b) return value >=1
if(a=b) return 0;
if(a<b) return value <=-1
```

Comment: Your first optimization is questionable.  It's hard to imagine `month * 64` being enough faster than `month * 1000` to make a difference, and if the OP is worried about that kind of efficiency, moving away from YMD timestamps is the way to go.  And then your second optimization is classically useless: any compiler can replace multiplications by shifts, so you get zero gain in efficiency and a significant loss in readability.  (Not to mention the possibility for error: your shifts are in the wrong direction).

Comment: @Steve Summit: Tanks for pointing out the shift-direction-error. I corrected it. And as I said in my answer: 1 and 2 are at most **minor** improvements and must be validated by **profiling** like any optimization attempt.

Comment: It occurred to me later that if you're thinking about packing bit-width fields into a single integer, shifts are actually *more* readable than multiplications, not less.  (In other words, my complaint about a loss in readability might, arguably, have been backwards.)