# Why is pointing one position beyond a valid object acceptable for pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

In the textbook "Modern C" by Jens Gustedt, I read for pointers that "A pointer must point to a valid object or one position beyond a valid object or be null.". Why is pointing to one position beyond a valid object acceptable? E.g.:

```
int array[5] = {0};
int* p = array;
p = array + 5 // points to a valid location
p = array + 6 // points to an invalid location
```

Comment: Please cite the textbook. I'd like to read it.

Comment: `p = array + 5 // points to a valid location` -- No, it does not!

Comment: When iterating an array and post-incrementing a pointer, it allows the last element to be treated the same as the other elements without making a special case of it. Pointing to one beyond, does not mean that it can be dereferenced.

Comment: @JeffHolt The textbook is called "Modern C" written by Jens Gustedt.

Comment: @FredLarson: Re “points to a valid location”: There is slack in the terminology here. The C standard does not define this phrase. One could use “points to a valid location” to mean the pointer value is well defined but not that one can access an object at that location.

Comment: The quote is wrong; if it weren't, the code `int main () { int* p; }` were invalid, because an uninitialized pointer might point anywhere random. If you dereference a pointer, it has to point to a valid object. If you want to compare or subtract pointers, they have to point into or one-past the same array, or be null.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Does the standard *use* that phrase for this situation? "points to a valid location" to me means you could safely dereference it, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Alex [@JensGustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) (the author) is an active member here. Maybe he will answer what he meant himself. :-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil There are [argumentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932383/accessing-struct-elements-using-single-pointer/62933027#comment111291779_62932383) that even the incremented pointer value isn't well-defined because of  §6.5.6/8. How about that?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: The comment you point to does not say that. That comment is in the context where `p_a` points to a structure member, not to an array, and so `p_a+4` is not defined. That has nothing to do with pointer arithmetic within an array and the position one beyond its last element.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  I thought that too but §6.5.6/7 says "*For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.*" which made the premise that pointer to scalar objects apply to §6.5.6/8, too.

Comment: Yes, @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio.  So for any lvalue `x`, it is allowed to evaluate `&x + 1`, to store the result, and to work with it in a variety of ways.  That counts as a pointer to one element past the end of an array.  But for many -- ***although not all*** -- lvalues, computing `&x + 2`, `&x + 3`, *etc*. has undefined behavior, and you and M.M. were discussing one of those cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Supporting “one beyond the last” makes working with arrays simpler. For example, if a function is called with a pointer `Start` to some element, it might want to prepare an end pointer `End` and use a loop such as:

```
for (ElementType *p = Start; p < End; ++p)
```

To do this, `End` must be a valid pointer.

We might consider instead setting `End` to be the last element to be processed, rather than one beyond it, and using:

```
for (ElementType *p = Start; p <= End; ++p)
```

However, note that, after the final element is processed, `p` will be incremented to **beyond** `End`. Then, in order for `p <= End` to be a valid expression, `p` must be a valid pointer. So, we need to be able to do address arithmetic up to one beyond the last element of an array.

Comment: thanks for the answer, assigning to the location "one position beyond a valid object" through a pointer is still considered invalid, right?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, the pointer is valid (its value may be used in pointer comparisons and arithmetic), but attempting to access (read or write) what the pointer points to is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 3):

Your code comments express a probable misunderstanding.  With ...

> ```
> int array[5] = {0};
> int* p = array;
> p = array + 5 // points to a valid location
> ```

... `p` *does not* point to a valid location.  It is allowed and well defined to evaluate `array + 5`, and that produces a value that `p` can store, but undefined behavior results from any attempt to dereference that pointer value.

Such a value for `p` is sometimes useful as an exclusive upper bound on the addresses of elements of `array`, or for indexing `array` backwards (with strictly negative indexes), but you may not attempt to access a value through that value itself.

In contrast, in this case ...

> ```
> p = array + 6 // points to an invalid location
> ```

... `p` does not point to *anything*, at least inasmuch as can be determined by analysis of the code.  Attempting to evaluate the expression `array + 6` produces undefined behavior, and in particular, the result is not well defined.

Comment: Re “point to a valid location”: There is slack in the terminology here. The C standard does not define this phrase. One could use “point to a valid location” to mean the pointer value is well defined but not that one can access an object at that location.

Comment: I am not inclined to argue that point, @EricPostpischil.  My remarks about and using that phrase in this answer are directed toward interpreting the OP's use of it, and refuting what I take, in context, to be their most probable meaning.  It is possible that they in fact mean something different, in which case I think the difference in meaning between them and me will be clear to them from context.